# Question about double for loops and ranges

Tags: python

Since I am a beginner to python I was confused as to why j results to this:
0
1
0
1
2
when doing the code below.
From my understanding I thought, i represents 0-3 so wouldn't j represents the numbers 0-3 as well.

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(i):
        print(j)
```

Comment: Try to debug your code to get a better understanding.

Comment: It doesnt print when i is 0. And for every other iteration from 1 to 3, j runs from 0 to i-1.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: I added an image to my answer showing a simple way to debug with a print statement (for this example) and understand what is happening, if it helps.

Comment: You omitted this first 0. what would you expect instead of the observed behavior and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first for loop goes from 0 to 3.

So i is 0, then 1, then 2, then 3.

J is going to be 0, then 1, then 2, then 3.

So printing j in range (0) does nothing, because range(0) is nothing.

Then you print j in range(1), which prints 0

Then you print j in range(2) which prints 0, 1

Lastly you print j in range (3) which prints 0, 1, 2

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 iterations of the outer loop, for `i` set to 0, 1, 2, and 3.

The first one does nothing, as `range(0)` is an empty sequence.

The second one outputs 0, the only value in `range(1)`.

The third outputs 0 and 1, the values in `range(2)`.

The last prints 0, 1, and 2, the values in `range(3)`.

The key is that the inner call to `range` uses the current value of `i` to produce a range of values that does not *include* `i` itself.

Answer (score 0):

In this example for loop `for i in range(4)` will run while i is smaller than stop value which is in this case 4 (The last run of loop is going to be when i is 3). The default starting value for variable in range function is 0. If you pass two arguments to range function, first will be starting value, and second will be stop value (when variable isn't less then stop value, loop isn't going to run anymore). With every iteration, the starting value will increase by 1. You can change that number by passing third argument to range function. If start and stop value are same, for example 0 and 0, for loop won't run.

It's same with nested for loops, like in your example.
Hope I made you for loops little bit easier.ž